# How to Send then receive and store response correctly?

Tags: arduino

I’m learning as people from forums like this one have guided me.

I just learned how to send request to a sensor using serial communication, I used the following code to query the sensor.Expected query is:

```
  digitalWrite(mdDeRe, HIGH);  //tells the sensor serial data is coming.

Serial.write(17);
  Serial.write(3);
  Serial.write(0);    
  Serial.write(84); 
  Serial.write(0);
  Serial.write(4); 
  Serial.write(7);  
  Serial.write(73);  
  Serial.flush();
  delayMicroseconds(120);
  digitalWrite(mdDeRe,LOW);  

  ///sensor response is: 11 03 08 00 64 00 3E 00 0D 00 55 9C E8
  /// I would like to store the response in an array.

   if (Serial.available()) {
    for (int response=0; response<12; response ++){
    incomingByte[response] = Serial.read();
      }
    }
  }
/// Will this work?
/// Is there a more efficient or proper way to do the same?
```

Comment: I think you tagged your question wrongly, is this really javascript, or you mean java?

Comment: Hi! Actually it’s from the Arduino IDE .

Comment: you expect after one byte is available that the rest will be too. that is not true. the bytes arrive slow. `Serial.available()` returns count of characters available in the receive buffer. and don't send the request again anything until you received the response

Comment: Arduino is programmed in C++, not Javascript. Please do a minimum of research befor you post questions here. at least read the Arduino manual.

Comment: Juraj, Thank u for your time! Will this be better : if (Serial.available( ) >12) {
    for (int response=0; response<13; response ++){
    incomingByte[response] = Serial.read();
      }

Comment: Piglet, I apologize for the ignorance. I’m just learning how to use Arduino hardware and software, all the Jargons with the languages, c,c++, Java, JavaScript xml and so forth is overwhelming new to me. I would not know how to distinguish one line of code to the other. But I can decently learn from samples or guides and appreciate those that help in the process!  When you send someone to google is kinda discouraging becouse many times you don’t really know what you looking for!   For example encourage to get that simple answer like in my case was : create an array, send data from that array.